# Как передать компаратор в std::map

Tags: c++, map

Есть следующий код

```
typedef std::pair<double, double> Point;

bool cmp(const Point& p1,const Point& p2){
    if (p1.first != p2.first){
        return p1.first < p2.first;
    }
    return p1.second < p2.second;
}

int main() {
    std::map<Point, int> a;
}
```

Как передать `cmp()` в качестве компаратора в `std::map`?

Comment: Третьим параметром шаблона вестимо.

Comment: Я понимаю что через 3 параметр, компилятор пишет что функция не подходит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Шаблон `std::map` принимает компаратор в качестве третьего параметра. Но главное здесь то, что это должен быть класс с соответствующим `operator()`, поэтому вместо функции надо просто создать класс:

```
#include <map>

typedef std::pair<double, double> Point;

struct CMP {
    bool operator()(const Point& p1, const Point& p2) const {
        if (p1.first != p2.first){
            return p1.first < p2.first;
        }
        return p1.second < p2.second;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::map<Point, int, CMP> a;
}
```

Подойдёт и лямбда, но параметром всё равно будет тип, хоть и порождённый лямбдой. И для инстанцирования нужно будет явно передавать экземпляр как в ответе Fat-Zer.

```
auto l = [](const Point& p1, const Point& p2) { 
    if (p1.first != p2.first){
        return p1.first < p2.first;
    }
    return p1.second < p2.second; 
};

int main() {
    std::map<Point, int, decltype(l)> a(l);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

А если по каким-то причинам есть желание обойтись без функтора (хотя практических причин для этого я и не представляю), то можно изощриться как-то так:

```
std::map<Point, int, bool(*) (const Point& p1,const Point& p2)> a(cmp);
```

Начиная с c++11 это можно немного проще записать с помощью `decltype`¹:

```
std::map<Point, int, decltype(&cmp)> a(cmp);
```

---

<sup>¹ Спасибо **@αλεχολυτ** за уточнение</sup>